# All snap applications including software centre are not opening

Tags: firefox, software-center, snap, vlc

After a system update yesterday, none of my snap applications are opening. I tried to run the application via the terminal but I'm getting this error `/snap/firefox/1232/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 52: /home/ttumejiaku/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied` . This is the contents of the path below `/home/ttumejiaku/.config/user-dirs.dirs:`

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Every other snap application is giving a similar error. I've tried to enable all permission via the settings interface but it's still not working. Pls, any way to resolve this? Thanks

this is the output of `ls -lah /home/ttumejiaku/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

`-rw------- 1 ttumejiaku ttumejiaku 633 Apr 23 13:35 /home/ttumejiaku/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Comment: I'm a new linux user, so I don't really understand what you want me to do? help me understand better

Comment: I just pasted the contents, I don't know if I did it correctly?

Comment: Good. Now show us the complete output of `ls -lah home/ttumejiaku/.config/user-dirs.dirs` in your question above.

Comment: this is what I got, `ls: cannot access 'home/ttumejiaku/.config/user-dirs.dirs': No such file or directory`

Comment: I've updated the result

Comment: Hmmm. Everything looks correct. Next thing to try is reinstalling snapd (`sudo apt install --reinstall snapd`) and rebooting your system. If reinstalling snapd  doesn't fix it, then we will hope for good ideas from somebody else.